# Language support for Point cloud library API

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, computational-geometry, point

I would like to know which languages can be used to access the Point cloud library API's directly without using any third party wrappers or libraries?

Point cloud library - www.pointclouds.org

Answer (score 0):

compile PCL from source is not easy, but the PCL version for["All-in-one installers (PCL + dependencies)"](http://www.pointclouds.org/downloads/windows.html) is a little old(only for VS2008, VS2010).
Here's is the newest PCL1.7.2 for VS2013["All-in-one installers (PCL + dependencies)"](http://yunpan.cn/cJhEE4eZa5JXv) download(password:706c)

Answer (score 0):

A **python** wrapper can be found [here](http://strawlab.github.io/python-pcl/) but it **may not support latest versions of PCL**

I think there are **no other wrappers** as of now.

Only **C++** is supported by Point Cloud Library.

For Windows, the latest installers for PCL 1.8.1 can be found [here](http://unanancyowen.com/en/pcl181/)

Comment: If that first link breaks, you will just have the word "here" - which isn't helpful. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)